# Using two BroadcastReceiver in a single application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android app which uses broadcastreceiver for push notifications. Now i want to listen for sms messages. My question is can i use another broadcast receiver for listening sms or use the previous broadcast receiver class for both(GCM push messages and sms)

Comment: is there any performance issue in creating two broadcast receiver in a single project

Comment: thank you @Shabbir Dhangot. Thank you for your quick response

Comment: Question is: are they doing the same things? if so, then make one common (or common base class and 2 recivers which are using base methods) ... if no then make 2 ...